# Controller-defined functions in recursively created directives using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a dynamic Tree component, i.e. like a folder structure. I would like the children to be load dynamically, so in contrast to other modules expecting the whole structure to be present during initialization, I would like to load the elements when needed.

Therefore I bind a controller function to the directive. This is my HTML:

```
<tree-model data="treedata" load-children="loadTree(n)" />
```

And this defines the `tree-model` directive

```
app.directive( 'treeModel', function( $compile, $log, $http ) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          node: '=data',
          loadChildren: '&'
        },
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
          var template =
            '<ul>' +
              '<li ng-model="node">' +
              '<span ng-switch="node.status">' +
                '<i ng-switch-when="collapsed" class="collapsed" ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)">C</i>' +
                '<i ng-switch-when="expanded" class="expanded" ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)">E</i>' +
                '<i ng-switch-default="" class="normal">N</i> ' +
              '</span>' +
              '<span ng-class="node.selected">{{node.label}}</span>' +
              '<span ng-repeat="c in node.children">' +
                '<tree-model data="c" load-children="loadChildren(n)" />' +
              '</span>' +
              '</li>' +
            '</ul>';

          var repl = function() {
            var newElement = angular.element(template);
            $compile(newElement)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(newElement);
          }

          scope.selectNodeHead = function(selectedNode) {
            if (selectedNode.children && selectedNode.children.length) {
              // Collapse
              selectedNode.children = undefined;
              selectedNode.hasChildren = true;
              selectedNode.status = "collapsed";
            } else {
              // Expand
              scope.loadChildren({n: selectedNode});
              selectedNode.status ="expanded";
              repl();
            }
          };

          repl();
        }
      };
    });
```

This is my controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',
  function ($scope, $log, $http) {
    $scope.treedata = { "label": "Root", "status": "collapsed", "screen": "Root", "id": "999999", "hasChildren": true };

    $scope.loadTree = function(node) {
      $scope.output = "Node: " + node;
      node.children =[
        { "label": "Child 1", "status": "collapsed", "screen": "Child 1", "id": "999997", "hasChildren": true},
        { "label": "Child 2", "status": "normal", "screen": "Child 2", "id": "999995", "hasChildren": false}
      ];
    };
  });
```

So I'd like to recursively build the tree. This works well for the first node and my controller function `loadTree()` gets the expected `node` as input. However, in the child step it calls `loadTree()`, but without passing `node` as parameter.

This seems to be somehow related to isolated scopes. If I do

```
scope.$parent.$parent.loadChildren({n: selectedNode});
```

instead of

```
scope.loadChildren({n: selectedNode});
```

in the expand part of the directive, the parameter passing works.

Here is a plunker to demonstrate the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/i4vDuCd7efmweZ9IZXMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you call your method inside the template in a directive. It should be called like this:

```
'<tree-model data="c" load-children="loadChildren({n : n})" />'
```

A slightly modified code of yours here:
http://jsfiddle.net/yyankowski/2zcpp/3/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! So simply and logical in the end, but I might have never though of this...